# How to enable the foreign key in sqlite through java code

Tags: sqlite

How to enable the foreign key in sqlite through java code.
My code to dbconnection is as follows:

`ctx = new InitialContext();
            ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/sqlite");
            connection = ds.getConnection();`

Comment: You just execute the [pragma](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_foreign_keys). What's the problem with this?

Comment: problem is if i execute the pragma in sqlite browser it will be valid only for a single db connection. Also my requirement is to enable the foreign key constraint through java code.

Comment: Do you know how to execute SQL from Java?

Comment: yes I know to execute

Comment: Can you send me that segment of code

Comment: actually it can be done like this

Comment: SQLiteConfig config = new SQLiteConfig();  
        config.enforceForeignKeys(true);  
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,config.toProperties());

Comment: but in my case im using ds.getconnection() instead of drivermanager.get